# style css working but link css not

Tags: css

Is there a reason my below CSS only half works?

```
div.share
{
    position:relative;
    top: -4px;
    left: 25px;
    font-family:Tahoma;
    background-color:#000000;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
/* share link css */
a.share:active
{
    color: #000000;

}
a.share:hover
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color:#000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The `div.share` CSS is all working but the CSS for the `active` and `hover` is not

Comment: Without seeing HTML there's not much we can do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS is valid, but make sure the link does have the "share" class, if its in the DIV, change the css to:

```
div.share a:active
{
        color: #000000;

}
div.share a:hover
{
        color: #FFFFFF;
        background-color:#000000;
        text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

adding your html would make this easier.

I can only guess that you have a `<div>` with `class='share'` and no `<a>` tag with the same.

e.g., does your html look like:

```
 <div class='share'>
   <a class='share' href='http://yoursite.com'>Your site</a>
 </div>
```

or

```
 <div class='share'>
 </div>
 ...
 <a class='share' href='http://yoursite.com'>Your site</a>
```

If it's the first, then

```
div.share a:hover {
  ...
}
```

would make more sense.

If it's the second, then the selector looks fine... though it might be better to choose different, but appropriate class names.

Answer (score 2):

Use `div.share a:active` and `div.share a:hover`.

The way you have it right now it is looking for an <a> tag with a share class applied directly. However the share class is on the outer div.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show us an HTML snippet using this CSS? Is it really the `<a>` tag that has the `share` class or is it nested inside the `<div class="share">`?